# PHPexcel formula cell getting overrided instead of replace on filter column

Tags: phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel_v1_8, I have implemented formula to some cells like following.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G4','=SUBTOTAL(2,B6:B'.$row.')'); 
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H4','=ROUND(SUBTOTAL(9,Q6:Q'.$row.'),2)');
```

I also tried like

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6,4,'=SUBTOTAL(2,B6:B'.$row.')');
```

Here $row means total number of rows.

But when I filter any column then it append/override value of formula applied cell. Please see following filtered total row.

[image]

I want only latest value should in filtered total row means want to replace existing value. Right now, I am getting correct value but why it is overrided? Any suggestions what can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You've actually discovered a genuine bug here.
I wasn't aware when I implemented the SUBTOTAL logic in PHPExcel that it only worked with visible rows, and ignored hidden rows. Can you please raise an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues)

However, reading through the [MS Excel docs](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) for SUBTOTAL, a function of `2` or `9` will return the result for all rows in the range (hidden or otherwise) while `102` or `109` will return the result only for visible rows